# Clojure how to stop all go blocks or close all channels in core.async

Tags: clojure, core.async

all to often when I'm using core.async from the repl a go block will get away from me because I loose the channel that is used to stop it because I reload a namespace. For instance if i run this from the repl:

```
(go (when (not= c (second (async/alts! [c (async/timeout 1000)]))) 
      (println "hello")))
```

and then I reload the namespace and c is lost. Now I have "hello" spamming my REPL until the end of time. If I could close all channels or kill all go blocks it would save me restarting my REPL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to do this globally that I know of. One technique is to use a control channel that can be used to shut down any loop. The [pub/sub](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/pub) stuff might work well for a global control channel.